# 16.04 LTS on Virtualbox - Drag/Drop from PC to Ubuntu Not Working

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, drag-and-drop

Setup:
Win10 on Dell 8900 
Virtualbox - Latest version
Virtualbox Extensions - Latest version
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - All updates installed
Bidirectional Drag/Drop Enabled

I can drag files from Ubuntu to PC without a problem.  When I drag from PC to Ubuntu it looks like it is working fine.  I get '+ Copy' symbol and I get busy symbol (blue circle) for a second but nothing appears in directory.  I've tried Downloads, Documents and Desktop directory as well as others.

The bidirectional clipboard works perfectly.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 12):

I figured out it sort of works.  The file is transferred to /tmp/VirtualBox Dropped Files/'time stamped dir'/'file'.  It doesn't put it in dropped folder.  You can manually move it.  /tmp/VirtualBox Dropped Files is deleted on reboot.

Comment: Is this a bug of Virtualbox? I meet this problem on Windows 10 host, with Virtualbox v5.2.6 run Ubuntu 16.04.4 GNOME as guest.

Comment: Looks like it is indeed a bug that is probably specific to the Ubuntu implementation of the Guest Additions: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16025?cversion=0&cnum_hist=1